# restricting access to staticcontent, urls in grails web-app

Tags: grails, groovy, security

I tried looking up any tips for restricting access to static content/partial urls on a web server for my grails web-app but getting confused about using  element in web.xml, since right now I am using the grails default jetty server (doesn't use web.xml) and the images, css, js etc are all accessible without any authentication. how do I go about restricting access to

1) all static content directories - only accessible in a valid user session.

2) all intermediate url paths not displaying content in the appropriate format/incorrect content.

It should say like not available/forbidden if the user tries to access above 2 by hitting urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your own filters (by URI) in grails-app/conf. For more details see section **6.6 Filters** in grails documentation

Answer (score 1):

... off the top of my head I'd try the spring-security plugin, it has options for restricting access on per url basis. Good start is here the [screencast](http://grails.org/screencast/show/11)